# Pass Repository Name to Slack bot during Cloud Build

Tags: go, slack, google-cloud-build

I am following [the documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/slackbot) to get a Slack bot to report on Cloud Build progress for a Project in Google Cloud Platform, using the Slack image found in [Google Cloud Builder Community](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community). I've been able to get the out-of-the-box messages to post successfully.

Since I have multiple repositories that will get built, I want to post the name of the Repository that is being built:

e.g.

```
Build bot: Repo Fizz-buzz built successfully...
Build bot: Repo Wizz-bang failed to build...
```

In the `Notify()` function, the `cloudbuild.Build` struct has a few properties that might do what I am wanting. The `Source.RepoSource.RepoName` looks ideal, but it's nil.

Another option would be to have the [trigger()](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/271173e4539787c5c8a7a0c16a5e767598b932c8/slackbot/slackbot/trigger.go#L18) function add the repository name as an argument:

```
Args: []string{
                    fmt.Sprintf("--build=%s", build),
                    fmt.Sprintf("--webhook=%s", webhook),
                    fmt.Sprintf("--repoName=%s", repoName),
                    "--mode=monitor",
                },
```

I'd prefer to have the Notify() function handle this, but I haven't found the appropriate struct property.

Is there a property that I can use during the [notify()](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/07ff8507dd8bfac6ebd7ea291ba3d9f7515123d8/slackbot/slackbot/notify.go#L14) function to pass along the repository name?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the official documentation of Cloud Build, as per is mentioned [1]: 

$REPO_NAME: build.Source.RepoSource.RepoName (only available for triggered builds)

As you mentioned the option could be use the trigger () function.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use github app triggered builds and use `build.substitutions.REPO_NAME`